# Declaring an instance of a class with val

Tags: class, scala, immutability

In Scala, the `val` keyword declares an immutable variable. So if you declare `val x = 3`, it stays 3. But if you use `var`, it can change.

But what happens if you declare an instance of a class with `val`? For example, take this class `Point`

```
   class Point(_x: Int, _y: Int) {
       var x = _x
       var y = _y

       def doubleValues = {
           x *= 2
           y *= 2
       }
   }
```

First, I declare `var location = new Point(2,2)`
Then run

```
  println(location.x)
  println(location.y)

  location.doubleValues

  println(location.x)
  println(location.y)
```

The output, as expected, is

```
2
2
4
4
```

But if I rerun and use the `val` keyword to declare location, the result is the same. So even though `location` was declared immutable, the mutable variables inside it are still mutable.

So then what does actually happen when you declare an instance of a class with `val` ? What exactly is the difference between using `var` and `val`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a `var` you can change which `Point` it is; with a `val` you can't:

```
var x = new Point(2, 2)
x = new Point(3, 2)
val y = new Point(2, 2)
y = new Point(3, 2) // won't compile
```

Conversely if I make an object containing a `val`, I can't change that value "inside" the object, even though I can change the object itself:

```
class Q(i: Int) {val x: Int = i}
var q = new Q(4)
q = new Q(6)
q.x = 2 // won't compile
```

To make an object truly immutable you need to use `val` "all the way down". A common pattern is to have all your "inner" objects immutable, and then have some "top-level" object which is mutable, either explicitly (with `var`) or by using something like the `State` monad. There's relatively little value in having an "immutable" object with mutable members.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer to the object is immutable, not the object itself.